# How to create an ADODB Recordset From a Table Valued Function with Named Parameters

Tags: sql-server, vba, ado, user-defined-functions

This works:

```
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
rst.Open "SELECT * FROM dbo.ftblTest(1,2,3)", CP.Connection, adOpenKeyset, adLockReadOnly
```

But it would be nicer to do this:

```
rst.Open "SELECT * FROM dbo.ftblTest(@Param1=1,@Param2=2,@Param3=3)", CP.Connection, adOpenKeyset, adLockReadOnly
```

If I try the second method I get the error: "parameters were not supplied for the function ftblTest"

Is it possible to use named parameters with multi-statement table-valued functions?

**Edit 1: Examples Added Using Command Object**

*First the SQL*

```
create function ftblTest (@Input int)
RETURNS @Results TABLE (
  OutputField int
  )
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO @Results SELECT @Input
Return
End
```

*Some Code* (run from inside an Access 2003 ADP, with a connection to the correct SQL DB)

```
Public Sub test()
  Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
  Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command

  'method 1 works
  rst.Open "SELECT * FROM dbo.ftblTest(2)", CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenKeyset, adLockReadOnly
  Debug.Print rst.Fields(0)
  rst.Close

  With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
    .CommandType = adCmdTable

    'method 2 works
    .CommandText = "dbo.ftblTest(3)"
    Set rst = cmd.Execute
    Debug.Print rst.Fields(0)

    'method 3 fails
    .CreateParameter "@Input", adInteger, adParamInput, , 4
    .CommandText = "dbo.ftblTest(@Input)"
    Set rst = cmd.Execute 'error here:-2147217900   Must declare the scalar variable "@Input".
    Debug.Print rst.Fields(0)

  End With
End Sub
```

How can I get the named parameters to work in method 3?

**Edit 2: test code modified to use Parameters.Append**

```
Public Sub test()
  Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
  Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
  Dim p As New ADODB.Parameter

  With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
    .CommandType = adCmdTable

    'Parameter Append method fails
    p = .CreateParameter("@Input", adInteger, adParamInput, , 4)
    Debug.Print p.Name, p.Type = adInteger, p.Direction = adParamInput, p.SIZE, p.Value 'note that name not set!
    With p
      .Name = "@Input"
      .Type = adInteger
      .Direction = adParamInput
      .SIZE = 4 'this shouldn't be needed
      .Value = 4
    End With
    Debug.Print p.Name, p.Type = adInteger, p.Direction = adParamInput, p.SIZE, p.Value 'properties now set
    .Parameters.Append p
    .CommandText = "dbo.ftblTest(@Input)"
    Set rst = cmd.Execute 'error here:-2147217900   Must declare the scalar variable "@Input".
    Debug.Print rst.Fields(0)

  End With
End Sub
```

this still doesn't work.

**Edit 3: I removed the @ from create parameter**

as suggested and tried the CommandText 3 ways and got 3 different errors:

```
.CommandText = "dbo.ftblTest"
```

error: Parameters were not supplied for the function 'dbo.ftblTest'.

```
.CommandText = "dbo.ftblTest()"
```

error: An insufficient number of arguments were supplied for the procedure or function dbo.ftblTest.

```
.CommandText = "dbo.ftblTest(Input)"
```

error: "Input" is not a recognized table hints option. If it is intended as a parameter to a table-valued function or to the CHANGETABLE function, ensure that your database compatibility mode is set to 90.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command

With cmd

    .ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
    .CommandType = adCmdTable
    'you need to add question a mark for each parameter
    .CommandText = "dbo.ftblTest(?)"
    'you can even add a order by expression like:
    .CommandText = "dbo.ftblTest(?) ORDER BY ..."
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@Input", adInteger, adParamInput, , 4)
    
    Set rst = cmd.Execute 
    Debug.Print rst.Fields(0)

End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use parameters with a table function.

```
rst.Open "SELECT * FROM dbo.ftblTest(@Param1,@Param2,@Param3)", CP.Connection, adOpenKeyset, adLockReadOnly
```

Before you open the database connection add parameters and set their values.

Comment: not sure exactly how I should do that.  I will add examples to my question.

Comment: Look at the link that @Remou added.  That appears to show the syntax on how to add a parameter.

Comment: had a look at that and added the Parameters.Append bit but it still doesn't work.  see new example code above.

Comment: At this point we've got a little of the blind leading the blind here.  I'll see if I can't grab someone who knows a little move about coding.  What language are you using?

Comment: Thanks mrdenny.  I'm using a MS Access 2003 ADP, so the language is VBA, data access is ADODB2.5 and database is a MS SQL Server 2008 database.  See new comment on Robert's answer.  I'm starting to wonder if using named parameters on Ta able-Valued Function may not be possible.

Comment: I'm sure that it is. Its just a matter of getting the syntax correct.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the @ in the name of your parameter and don't list the parameter by name in the command text. I've always done this with a stored procedure, so I'm not sure exactly how the paranethesis are handle for the command text.

try:

.CreateParameter "Input", adInteger, adParamInput, , 4

And:

.CommandText = "dbo.ftblTest()"

Or:

.CommandText = "dbo.ftblTest"

Comment: I removed the @ from create parameter, tried the CommandText 3 ways and got 3 different errors:

    .CommandText = "dbo.ftblTest"
    error: Parameters were not supplied for the function 'dbo.ftblTest'.

    .CommandText = "dbo.ftblTest()"
    error: An insufficient number of arguments were supplied for the procedure or function dbo.ftblTest. 

    .CommandText = "dbo.ftblTest(Input)"
    error: "Input" is not a recognized table hints option. If it is intended as a parameter to a table-valued function or to the CHANGETABLE function, ensure that your database compatibility mode is set to 90.